# clicking a button shows a new Jpanel

Tags: java, swing

Hey I'm working on a java project, I'll try yo generalize my problem so...

I have a jpanelX that contains jbuttons1 to 5. All these jbuttons connect to the same actionlistener and the same action performed method. I also save the source of the button clicked into a global string variable.

I have another JpanelY. JpanelY contains arrays of strings.

I want to connect the two with this behavior:

- user clicks button1 on JpanelX
- JpanelY is shown instead of JpanelX. aka the user is taken to JpanelY
- the string array in JpanelY will contain different values based on the clicked Jbutton. So if a user clicks Jbutton1, the array will be assigned values {"Value1 ","value 1b","value1c"}

i tried a lot of things and got different errors. please help me, thank you so much

Comment: It will be nice to see what you have already done. Please edit your answer and post a minimal example showing your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870789/3992939

Comment: I think your question is too broad. If you are asking about switching JPanels, look into CardLayout. If you want to resolve your errors, you will have to post your codes and what error you are getting. Or even better, try to debug your own code first before asking here..

Comment: *"i tried a lot of things and got different errors."* Try 1) Posting the errors as an [edit]. 2) Posting a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Asking a question.

Comment: there's no reason to be rude. if you want to help then thank you, if not then please don't. I don't understand why people in computer science like to stretch their technical muscles on someone less knowledgeable than them. I couldn't post my code because it's for a school project, and my teacher will consider it plarigism if my code is found online. Computer Science = Arrogant culture!!

Answer (score 0):

- It's a bad idea to save anything in a global string variable. Much better is to call a method in the panel you wish to display that assigns the correct values to your string array.
- A user can be 'taken to' a panel in lots of different ways. You could hide the current panel and show the new one (`setVisible(true/false)`), you could use a layout manager that allows different panels to be displayed in the same space, you could change the contents of the containing panel. You'll need to give more details of what you want.

Depending on what you need, you might end up with code like:

```
button1.addActionListener(ae-> showValues("val1", "val2");
button2.addActionListener(ae-> showValues("val3", "val4", "val5");

private void showValues(String... values) {
    setVisible(false);
    arrayPanel.setArray(values);
    arrayPanel.setVisible(true);
}
```