# Switching between different panels in Java to create a GUI interface

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm trying to write a program to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit or Fahrenheit Celsius based on the users choice (all GUI using AWT and Swing).

How to allow one method to change the visibility of the others in order to change what part of the program is visible?

Below is my code because my exact issue is difficult to explain:

```
package javapp1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
 *
 * @author logan
 */
public class FahrenheitToCelsius extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel startPanel;
    private JPanel fahrenheitToCelsiusPanel;
    private JPanel celsiusToFahrenheitPanel;
    private JLabel decideLabel;
    private JLabel FahrenheitToCelsiusLabel;
    private JLabel CelsiusToFahrenheitLabel;
    private JTextField FahrenheitToCelsiusText;
    private JTextField CelsiusToFahrenheitText;
    private JButton fahrenheitButton;
    private JButton celsiusButton;
    private JButton calcButton;
    private JButton exitButton;
    private JButton backButton;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 100;

    public FahrenheitToCelsius()
    {
        setTitle("Fahrenheit/Celsius Conversion");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildStartPanel();
        add(startPanel);
    }

    private void buildStartPanel()
    {
        decideLabel = new JLabel("Would you like to convert from Celsius or Fahrenheit?");

        fahrenheitButton = new JButton("Fahrenheit");

        fahrenheitButton.addActionListener(new FahrenheitToCelsiusListener());

        celsiusButton = new JButton("Celsius");

        celsiusButton.addActionListener(new CelsiusToFahrenheitListener());

        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

        startPanel = new JPanel();

        startPanel.add(decideLabel);
        startPanel.add(fahrenheitButton);
        startPanel.add(celsiusButton);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildFahrenheitToCelsiusPanel()
    {   
        FahrenheitToCelsiusLabel = new JLabel("Enter the degrees Fahrenheit");

        FahrenheitToCelsiusText = new JTextField(10);

        calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        calcButton.addActionListener(new CalculateFtoC());

        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

        backButton = new JButton("Back");
        backButton.addActionListener(new BackButtonListener());

        fahrenheitToCelsiusPanel = new JPanel();

        fahrenheitToCelsiusPanel.add(FahrenheitToCelsiusLabel);
        fahrenheitToCelsiusPanel.add(FahrenheitToCelsiusText);
        fahrenheitToCelsiusPanel.add(calcButton);
        fahrenheitToCelsiusPanel.add(exitButton);
    }

    private void buildCelsiusToFahrenheitPanel()
    {
        CelsiusToFahrenheitLabel = new JLabel("Enter the degree Celsius");

        CelsiusToFahrenheitText = new JTextField(10);

        calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        calcButton.addActionListener(new CalculateCtoF());

        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

        backButton = new JButton("Back");
        backButton.addActionListener(new BackButtonListener());

        celsiusToFahrenheitPanel = new JPanel();

        celsiusToFahrenheitPanel.add(CelsiusToFahrenheitLabel);
        celsiusToFahrenheitPanel.add(CelsiusToFahrenheitText);
        celsiusToFahrenheitPanel.add(calcButton);
        celsiusToFahrenheitPanel.add(exitButton);

    }

    private class FahrenheitToCelsiusListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            startPanel.setVisible(false);
            celsiusToFahrenheitPanel.setVisible(false);
            buildFahrenheitToCelsiusPanel();

        }
    }

    private class CelsiusToFahrenheitListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            startPanel.setVisible(false);
            fahrenheitToCelsiusPanel.setVisible(false);
            buildCelsiusToFahrenheitPanel();
        }
    }

    private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private class BackButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            fahrenheitToCelsiusPanel.setVisible(false);
            celsiusToFahrenheitPanel.setVisible(false);
            buildStartPanel();
        }
    }

    private class CalculateFtoC implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String input;
            int celsius;
            int fahrenheit;

            input = FahrenheitToCelsiusText.getText();

            fahrenheit = Integer.parseInt(input);

            celsius = ((fahrenheit-32)*(5/9));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fahrenheit+" degrees fahrenheit is "+celsius+" degrees celsius.");
        }
    }

    private class CalculateCtoF implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String input;
            int celsius;
            int fahrenheit;

            input = CelsiusToFahrenheitText.getText();

            celsius = Integer.parseInt(input);

            fahrenheit = ((celsius*(9/32))+32);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, celsius+" degrees celsius is "+fahrenheit+" degrees fahrenheit.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new FahrenheitToCelsius();
    }
}
```

Comment: The basic answer to your question is to use a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). The more complicated answer would require you to use some kind of controller, which, based on the input coming from the user, would be able to switch the panels

Comment: See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870789/3992939)

Comment: I've also written a blog post about how to use CardLayout - http://www.code4human.com/java-layout-manager-tutorial/4/