# How to completely close JPanel without closing the whole program?

Tags: java, swing

I want to close/terminate/throw away a JPanel that was created by a line of code (so it's completely terminated, not just hidden and running in the background as `setVisible(False);` does) and without closing the whole program as `System.exit(0);` does.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Your question seems to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) in disguise. What do you mean by "running in background"? If you want it no longer visible, set it invisible via `setVisible(false)` or swap components using a CardLayout.

Comment: If from some reason you want to prevent the `JPanel` from being referenced, you `setVisible(false)`  or use [CardLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870789/3992939) to hide it, and then set it to null.

Comment: @c0der: please don't propagate that fallacy.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels could you elaborate on what's wrong with setting a private reference to null ?

Comment: @c0der: it puts much too much importance on the variable and not on the object and its references where the importance belongs. Nulling a variable only occasionally releases all references to an object, and almost never to a complex object such as a Swing component since the JPanel will almost assuredly have many hidden internal references held by the Swing internals. It would give the OP the false sense that he's doing something useful when in fact he's not.

Comment: More importantly, we still have no idea form the original poster of what is driving this question, why he/she is asking it in the first place, because I still suspect that he's trying to solve a completely different problem and likely in the wrong way. I hope that he/she hasn't abandoned the question.

Comment: I have to agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels on all counts.

Comment: for example, there are timers that starts with the panel that executes several commands. I want to destroy/throw away every component that was initialized with that panel with a single line and not just hide it. Just like the dispose function for jFrame. what's the alternative for a panel ? that's my question @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 1):

> I want to close/terminate/throw away a JPanel that was created by a line of code (so it's completely terminated, not just hidden and running in the background as setVisible(False); does) and without closing the whole program as System.exit(0); does.

There's nothing wrong with simply calling `setVisible(false)` on the JPanel, or better, swapping it for another via CardLayout.

It appears that you're looking for some micro-optimization, but you're not going to get much by chasing this. Make it non-visible and move on..... unless of course there are more details about your code and your problem that we're currently not aware of, and if so, then please let us know.

Comment: That's not what he asked.  He asked a very specific question about closing a jpanel.  You didn't answer the question, you offered an opinion,

Comment: @user6629913: please define for me just what it means to "close a JPanel"? Then explain how that specific question can be answered. It's an essentially meaningless statement I'm afraid, and if I'm guilty of any sin, it's answering too soon, and before the original poster has done anything to clarify his question.

Comment: all of the reasons I can think of for doing what the OP asked for all point back to misunderstandings or very bad ideas for constructing a jpanel in the first place. We need more details.

Comment: @D-Klotz, yep, and I think that we'll likely never get those details as the question seems abandoned

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels,  I can't answer that question because I'm not the OP.  You're right though, if you didn't understand the question, you should have asked for clarification before offering a solution.  Why the rush?  Is reputation more important than accuracy?  In the end, you answered a question the OP didn't ask.

Comment: @user6629913: I could care less about reputation, but best practice I do care about, and hence my recommendation..

Comment: @GhostCat: yes, it does appear as if he/she are requesting a 3rd party library