# How to switch JPanel from different classes with mouseClicked?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm learning javax.swing right now and I'm just trying some things out. But now I'm facing a problem I just can't solve. When I click the JLabel for changing the page (jpanel), nothing happens. It won't remove and show the other jpanel.

I also added a

```java
    public final HomeGUI getMainFrame() {
    return this;
    }
```

and at the mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)

```java
    gui.getMainFrame().removeAll();
```

and I tried it also with

```java
    gui.getMainFrame().mainPanel.removeAll();
```

**My GUI:**

```java
    public class HomeGUI extends JFrame {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(cl);
        Panel panel;
        Page2 page2;

        public HomeGUI() {
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setSize(1200, 650);
            this.setTitle("Terminal");
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,1));

            panel = new Panel();
            panel.Inhalt();

            page2 = new Page2();
            page2.Inhalt();

            this.add(mainPanel);
            mainPanel.add(panel, "Seite1");
            mainPanel.add(page2, "Seite2");

            cl.show(mainPanel, "panel");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            HomeGUI terminal = new HomeGUI();
            terminal.setResizable(false);
            terminal.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

**the Panel:**

```java
    class Panel extends JPanel {
        private HomeGUI gui;
        Page2 page2;
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JPanel Panel;
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Willkommen");
        JLabel bgc = new JLabel("");
        JLabel menuStrich = new JLabel();
        JLabel menuTitle = new JLabel("Menu");
        JLabel menuHome = new JLabel("Home");
        JLabel menuSeite2 = new JLabel("Seite2");

        public void Inhalt() {
            this.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
            this.add(title);
            this.add(bgc);
            this.setLayout(null);

            //Seite1
            title.setSize(300, 50);
            title.setLocation(300, 20);
            title.setFont(new Font("Alba Matter", Font.PLAIN, 48));

            //Menu
            bgc.setLayout(null);
            bgc.setOpaque(true);
            bgc.setBackground(new Color(66, 78, 245));
            bgc.setSize(280, 650);
            bgc.setLocation(0, 0);
            bgc.add(menuTitle);
            bgc.add(menuStrich);
            bgc.add(menuHome);
            bgc.add(menuSeite2);

            menuTitle.setLocation(90, 10);
            menuTitle.setSize(100, 50);
            menuTitle.setFont(new Font("Bahnschrift", Font.PLAIN, 38));
            menuTitle.setForeground(Color.white);

            menuStrich.setLocation(10, 55);
            menuStrich.setSize(260, 5);
            menuStrich.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
            menuStrich.setOpaque(true);

            menuHome.setLocation(30, 70);
            menuHome.setSize(200, 50);
            menuHome.setFont(new Font("Concert One", Font.PLAIN, 36));
            menuHome.setForeground(Color.white);

            menuSeite2.setLocation(30, 130);
            menuSeite2.setSize(200, 50);
            menuSeite2.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            menuSeite2.setFont(new Font("Concert One", Font.PLAIN, 32));
            menuSeite2.addMouseListener(new menuSeite2Event());
        }

        private class menuSeite2Event extends MouseAdapter {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //show page2
                gui.cl.show(gui.mainPanel, "page2");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                menuSeite2.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                menuSeite2.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            }
        }
    }
```

```java
    class Page2 extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JPanel Panel;
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Willkommen");
        JLabel bgc = new JLabel("");
        JLabel menuStrich = new JLabel();
        JLabel menuTitle = new JLabel("Menu");
        JLabel menuHome = new JLabel("Home");
        JLabel menuSeite2 = new JLabel("Seite2");

        public void Inhalt() {
            this.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
            this.add(title);
            this.add(bgc);
            this.setLayout(null);

            //Seite1
            title.setSize(300, 50);
            title.setLocation(300, 20);
            title.setFont(new Font("Alba Matter", Font.PLAIN, 48));

            //Menu
            bgc.setLayout(null);
            bgc.setOpaque(true);
            bgc.setBackground(new Color(66, 78, 245));
            bgc.setSize(280, 650);
            bgc.setLocation(0, 0);
            bgc.add(menuTitle);
            bgc.add(menuStrich);
            bgc.add(menuHome);
            bgc.add(menuSeite2);

            menuTitle.setLocation(90, 10);
            menuTitle.setSize(100, 50);
            menuTitle.setFont(new Font("Bahnschrift", Font.PLAIN, 38));
            menuTitle.setForeground(Color.white);

            menuStrich.setLocation(10, 55);
            menuStrich.setSize(260, 5);
            menuStrich.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
            menuStrich.setOpaque(true);

            menuHome.setLocation(30, 70);
            menuHome.setSize(200, 50);
            menuHome.setFont(new Font("Concert One", Font.PLAIN, 36));
            menuHome.setForeground(Color.white);
            menuHome.addMouseListener(new menuHomeEvent());

            menuSeite2.setLocation(30, 130);
            menuSeite2.setSize(200, 50);
            menuSeite2.setForeground(Color.white);
            menuSeite2.setFont(new Font("Concert One", Font.PLAIN, 32));
        }

        private class menuHomeEvent extends MouseAdapter {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //show Home
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                menuHome.setForeground(Color.CYAN);

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                menuHome.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            }
        } 
    }
```

INFO: all classes are in 1 file.

Comment: 1. I don't see `HomeGUI gui` nor `Page2 page2` ever initialized in `Panel`  2. Do not use null layout managers. Instead use appropriate [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)  3. To swap `JPanels` use `CardLayout` as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870789/3992939)  4. Use [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) *"When I click the JLabel for changing the page.."* Use a `JButton` instead. Add an `ActionListener` rather than a `MouseListener`, as it will react to both mouse & keyboard input. 3) But first heed the tips of @c0der.

Comment: BTW Don't use `Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - this.getWidth()) / 2);
            int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - this.getHeight()) / 2);
            this.setLocation(x, y);` since `this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` is a lot shorter (& achieves the same result).

Comment: Thank you all for the fast responde. I tried everything what you said, but every time I get this error from the eclipse console: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" at `gui.cl.show(gui.mainPanel, "page2");`. I looked up what the Problem is and found that "page2" does not have any declaration, but it has? I edidet my post and updated the code. Please have a look at it and tell me how I can fix this.

Comment: *"I tried everything what you said"* Who is 'you'? Tip: Add @c0der (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. If that comment was directed at me, @ notify me & I'll read it closely, now closing this tab I left open to check later..

Comment: For more help please post [mcve]. 
I find MCVE. Not only it makes helping much easier, it 
is a powerful debugging tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem. It should include all needed imports, and the full error message (stack trace). Also mark with a comment which line throws the exception.

Comment: See point 1 in my first comment : I do not see `HomeGUI gui;` nor `Page2 page2;` ever initialized in `Panel`. The code has many other issues like using `JLable`s where you should use buttons (see Andrew Thompson's comment) , setting layout manager to a `JLabel` (????) and adding other components to it, using inconsistent panel names and more. Go back to the basics, build a solid gui layout first before attempting to swap panels.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code has far too many problems and does not represent one well defined concise programming issue.